# Only Numbers in regex, negative numbers also

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I had to split a string into his numbers.

For example the string looks like that:

```
VAR_1123 Var_G -12.34 VAR-14.34 12.4 12 -234
```

The result i'd like:

```
-12.34,
12.4
12
-234
```

I try this Regular Expression:

```
([\-]?[0-9]+[\.[0-9]+]?)
```

But the result includes also 1123 and -14.34.

How can i exclude all numbers that have an underscore or a character bevor?

For testing i use this link:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use parentheses instead of a character class to group the dot and the last digits.
- Use `?:` to mean a non-capturing match.
- Change `[\-]` to simply `-`.
- Use lookaheads or lookbehinds to check for surrounding whitespace.

So the final regular expression looks like this:

```
(?<=\s|^)-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=\s|$)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/hyEYI)

Comment: But there will be a mismatch, when there is a valid number right at the beginning of the test string.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are :-)

```
(?<=\A|\s)-?[\d.]+\b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\s\-*\d\S*\d
```

Prefix whitespace, possible negative, digit bounded with possible characters between the bounds. Works, but obviously could be improved to cover more cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only additional criterion you need is that numbers should have whitespace before them, so this should work -

`\s[\-]?[0-9]+[\.[0-9]+]?`

I just added a `\s` before your regex. It works as you want on the examples you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern instead

```
([$\s][\-]?[0-9]+[\.[0-9]+]?)
```

EDIT - Change parantheses so that \s is not caught.

```
[$\s]([\-]?[0-9]+[\.[0-9]+]?)
```